# Calling REST API in Snowflake

Tags: api, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a usecase where in API's are published internally. Not using AWS Gateway or Azure. API's are deployed OnPrem. How can i use Snowflake External or internal functions to load data accessing REST API published internally?

Comment: Hi - are you asking how to access an API that is only published (and therefore presumably only accessible) internally within your own company? If that is what you are asking then obviously the answer is that you can't access it from Snowflake as Snowflake doesn't sit within your own company

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Looks like we have to setup AWS API gateway which accesses our internal site and then Snowflake should be able to access it through integration object.